# Where can I find a copy of 'The Serpent and Drakes of Tokoyokoku' book?

Tags: genshin-impact

I am working through my old quests and am working on *Collection of Dragon and Snakes* world quest. This quest has you going to find five books which are returned to the library in Enkanomiya.

I have found four of the five required books, but I am having some trouble with the last one.

[This guide from Polygon.com](https://www.polygon.com/genshin-impact-guides/22870367/collect-the-five-lost-books-collection-of-dragon-and-snakes-world-quest-book-locations-enkanomiya#aCGVR0) states that I can buy it from the Yae Publishing House.

However now that I have done the Yae Miko story quest, the vendor does not give me a buy dialog.

Instead he talks about the end of the Yae Miko story quest, and when you click the interaction just stops.

[image: Lady Guuji has an eye for things like this. If she thinks your work is interesting, you can be sure it's destined for success.]

What confuses me is that the quest tracker says I should return to Enkanomiya.

[image: Please head to Enkanomiya]

When I query the librarian about the book he tells that it was borrowed by someone from Narukami Island, which is where Yae Publishing House is located.

[image: According to the loan records, this was borrowed by an envoy from Narukami Island. I doubt we're getting this one back, honestly.]

How can I complete this quest and find a copy of *The Serpent and Drakes of Tokoyokoku* if I am unable to buy it from the vendor as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this quest was blocked by being in the middle of the Yae Miko story quest [The Great Narukami Offering](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/The_Great_Narukami_Offering).

Once I completed the final steps of this quest I was able to purchase the book.

[image: Greetings! Welcome to Yae Publishing House]

Comment: was going to ask the exact same thing... that line was a clear indication that you were still playing the quest. It should be what you get if you talk to Kuroda after getting the book endorsement during Friendship in Writing

Comment: BTW, what is really weird is that in this situation I would expect you get the usual message "This character is busy completing another quest" in the quest menu notices